# Уведомления о параллельных правках того же сообщения

Tags: дефект, предложение, правки

Исправлял пунктуационные и орфографические ошибки [сообщения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/77336#517469) из очереди проверок → <kbd>Сохранить изменения</kbd> →

[image: Ещё одна правка ожидает утверждение]

> Ещё одна правка этого сообщения ожидает утверждения. Нельзя вносить новые правки до рассмотрения уже отправленных.

Такое уже третий раз. Не очень приятно, когда несколько минут зря тратишь на корректуру и оформление.

Предлагаю ввести уведомления об одновременных параллельных правках сообщения.

Comment: См. также (и то, почему надо быть осторожнее с такими вещами): http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/500866/181100